# MySQL - Build a query string

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried aLL of the below yet I can't seem to get it working

```
$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = {$_GET[wkd]} WHERE id = 2";    
$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = '$_GET[wkd]' WHERE id = 2";    
$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = '"{$_GET[wkd]}"' WHERE id = 2";    
$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = '."{$_GET[wkd]}".' WHERE id = 2";
```

What is the correct way?
Thanks

Comment: Just as a note:  those are php syntax issues, not MySQL.

Comment: None of them are correct. You shouldn't be constructing your queries via concatenation and you shouldn't be using unsanitised data.

Comment: I suggest you look into PHP - PDO for database CRUD operations...

Comment: Assuming 'weekday' is a text field then: _`$sql = "UPDATE filename SET weekday = '{$_GET['wkd']}' WHERE id = 2";`_ expands correctly. However, _prepared queries_ are a lot easier and very much safer.

Comment: @pala_ the data is sanitised elsewhere - this is not the complete code.  I'm just trying to get the syntax right - amongst literally dozens of different arrangements shown on various websites.

Comment: @Mffffffffffffff You welcome. If you do not mind sharing the whole code then you may get more and accurate help for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way? Assuming `$link` is your `mysqli_connect`

```
$wkd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['wkd']);

$sql = "UPDATE filename SET weekday = '" . $wkd . "' WHERE id = 2";
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = '" . $_GET['wkd'] . "' WHERE id = 2";
```

FYI, this is very bad coding practice, you should validate $_GET before add to sql.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case $_GET['wkd'] is already validated higher up in the code.

Comment: he is not 'validating' $_GET , He is building your query string based on the value of $_GET so if $_GET['wkd'] is monday then $sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = ;monday' WHERE id = 2'... Did you manage to get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. If weekday accepts string values, then the value needs to be surrounded with quotes, ie:

`$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = '" . $_GET['wkd'] . "' WHERE id = 2";`

This is also equivalent to:

`$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = '{$_GET['wkd']}' WHERE id = 2";`

The first concatenates the string together, the second simply inserts the variable directly into the string.

For `$_GET['wkd'] = "tuesday";`, bot of those queries output this:

`UPDATE filename SET weekday = 'tuesday' WHERE id = 2`

If weekday only accepts numeric values, then there is no need to surround the value with quotes (but you still can):

`$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = " . $_GET['wkd'] . " WHERE id = 2";`

Which like the first, is equivalent to:

`$sql="UPDATE filename SET weekday = {$_GET['wkd']} WHERE id = 2";`

Which for `$_GET['wkd'] = 1`, will have both queries output:

`UPDATE filename SET weekday = 1 WHERE id = 2`

Point is - there is no one correct syntax, they'd all work.

However, what you really want to be doing is using pdo or mysqli with prepared statements and parameter binding, like so:

```
$pdo = new PDO('... connection string ... ');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE filename SET weekday = ? WHERE id = ?"); 
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['wkd'], 2));
```

This will bind the value of `$_GET['wkd']` to the first `?` in the prepared statement, and the literal `2` to the value of the second `?'.  If you find yourself using lots of question marks, or losing track of the order, you can also use named placeholders like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('... connection string ... ');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE filename SET weekday = :weekday WHERE id = :id"); 
$stmt->execute(array(
  'weekday' => $_GET['wkd'],
  'id' => 2
));
```

In that example i've named the placeholders the same as the fields - this isn't necessary but it is obviously more readable than naming the placeholders `:asdfasdf` and `:lmnop` (in which case the array being passed to the `execute` function would be `('asdfasdf' => $_GET['wkd'], 'id' => 2)`

Why use the parameter binding? Its your best defense against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)